# Printing the combined length of items in list for python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find out the combined length of all of the items inside of a list.

```
list = [12, 35]
```

i'm not quite sure how to calculate the len of all the items inside in one go, so that it returns '4', instead 2, the amount of items in the list. Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, integers have no len. So len(23) will rasie an error.

Comment: The items inside the list don't have a length, they're integers. I guess you could `sum(len(str(item)) for item in list)`, but it's not really clear what you're actually trying to achieve. Also, don't name your own list `list`, it shadows the built-in type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly more pythonic.

```
len(''.join(map(str, lst)))
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the length of a number is given by the number of digits.

The easiest way would be to convert everything to a string and then add their lengths:

```
>>> lst = [12, 35]
>>> sum(len(str(item)) for item in lst)
4
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i'm looking for, although i've now got a slightly different issue. When i put those commands into a python shell, it works as you did, but when i try to print the following "print sum(len(str(item)) for item in lst)", i just get a syntax error

Comment: If you're using python3 then `print` is a function, so it needs parenthesis: `print(sum(len(str(item)) for item in lst))`.